# How to edit xls file on server

Tags: excel

I have a Debian 7 server that hosts a rails application. In the application I need to let users download an xls file, but before downloading I need to customize the excel for the user. I need to edit the content in some cells.

The xls file that I need to edit has dropdown menus and links and formulas in it. Everything else but the edited cells should remain as they were.

I tried to open the xls with Spreadsheet gem, edited one of the cells and wrote the file back to disk. But the content in the file was mixed up badly after this small edit. It looked like there had occurred random edits all over the file.

```
excel = Spreadsheet.open '/path/to/original.xls'
sheet = excel.worksheet 2
sheet.rows[5][1] = 'New value'
excel.write '/path/to/edited.xls'
```

I believe Spreadsheet is the most robust xls file tool available as a rails gem. So the solution for this problem might involve using tools outside of rails.

Comment: In ruby there are indeed not much options for Excel. Perhaps you can convert it to xlsx and use the axlsx gem

Comment: Yes, that is why I didn't include ruby into the tags or title. If there is a good library in a different programming language, I would like to know.

Comment: Can I read an existing xlsx file with axlsx?

Comment: hm.. you can't :(. We used only for writing. I think you will be more happy with switching to java for that. There are a lot of choises for Excel as the Entreprise guys always want some Excel report. Before axls we used http://poi.apache.org/ (again only for writing) and consumed the excel export from JRUBY

Comment: poi.apache.org looks promising. Need to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Java and Apache POI are the solution.

With one class and a handful of methods I can read an existing xls file, do my modifications and write the file back to disk so that it can be sent to the user.